# onclick show div and hide other div doesn't work

Tags: jquery, css, show-hide

Could you please help me?

My code doens't work, the section doesnt appear after clicking the bottom section.

```
<script>
$("#img1").on('click', function() {
   $("#div1").fadeIn();
   $("#div2,#div3,#div4").fadeOut();
});
$("#img2").on('click', function() {
   $("#div2").fadeIn();
   $("#div1,#div3,#div4").fadeOut();
});
$("#img3").on('click', function() {
   $("#div3").fadeIn();
   $("#div1,#div2,#div4").fadeOut();
});
$("#img4").on('click', function() {
   $("#div4").fadeIn();
   $("#div1,#div2,#div3").fadeOut();
});
</script>
```

http://bookshark.phlexon.com/home-2/

Thanks so much!

Comment: Hello, please show us the relevant code that is enough to reproduce the problem, and not your website.

Comment: If you check the console of your browser, you can see you have an error: `TypeError: $ is not a function`. Make sure you have loaded all the scripts needed in order to make jquery work.

Comment: Try to keep the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) in mind and check if you can reduce that code.

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternate option other than by @aviboy2006.

You can insert the jQuery path to use the **$** sign.

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='dashicons-css'  href='http://bookshark.phlexon.com/wp-includes/css/dashicons.min.css?ver=5.4.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<!-- ****************** Add in jQuery path ************************************************-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- ***************************************************************************************-->
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://bookshark.phlexon.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://bookshark.phlexon.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/es6-promise@4/dist/es6-promise.auto.min.js?ver=5.4.1'></script>
```

Then, your code should be working as below: (wrap inside `$(document).ready(function(){`)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#img1").on('click', function() {
       $("#div1").fadeIn();
       $("#div2,#div3,#div4").fadeOut();
    });
    $("#img2").on('click', function() {
       $("#div2").fadeIn();
       $("#div1,#div3,#div4").fadeOut();
    });
    $("#img3").on('click', function() {
       $("#div3").fadeIn();
       $("#div1,#div2,#div4").fadeOut();
    });
    $("#img4").on('click', function() {
       $("#div4").fadeIn();
       $("#div1,#div2,#div3").fadeOut();
    });
});
```

Comment: @ЕленаЛинчук glad that I'm helping

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Your jQuery library is initiated but $ is not part of it.

```
<script>
jQuery("#img1").on('click', function() {
   jQuery("#div1").fadeIn();
   jQuery("#div2,#div3,#div4").fadeOut();
});
jQuery("#img2").on('click', function() {
   jQuery("#div2").fadeIn();
   jQuery("#div1,#div3,#div4").fadeOut();
});
jQuery("#img3").on('click', function() {
   jQuery("#div3").fadeIn();
   jQuery("#div1,#div2,#div4").fadeOut();
});
jQuery("#img4").on('click', function() {
   jQuery("#div4").fadeIn();
   jQuery("#div1,#div2,#div3").fadeOut();
});
</script>
```